# How to use swipe up and down to navigate between pages?

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, swipe, gesture

My basic question is: How do you swipe between pages up and down? I would like to have it so the page transition gets animated just as if you push a page on the navCtrl. Let me explain in more detail.

Here is my code for being able to swipe left and right:

HTML:

```
<ion-content (swipe)="swipeEvent($event)" padding>
  <ion-list>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
      {{ item.text }}
    </button>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Typescript:

```
  swipeEvent(e) {
    if (e.direction == 4) {
      this.navCtrl.pop();
    }
  }
```

I use direction == 2 for the swipe left to get to the page (push) and swipe right to go back (pop). The animation then transitions the page in from right to left, when I push. And the animations shows the page being wiped out from left to right when I pop.

So my questions are:

Is there a more efficient way to swipe between pages (left / right)?
How do I get the swipeEvent to recognize up and down (e.direction == 8 / 16 for up and down doesn't work)?

How do I get the page to be animated, that it transitions in from bottom to top when I push and transitions away from top to bottom when I pop?

I use Ionic 3.x on iOS Sierra on Mac.

Comment: You can control the navigation transition in a pop using the [navOptions](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#pop) Check under the navOptions title

Comment: I did read the documentation you posted. But I can't find the solution for my problem there. Am I missing something? As far as I'm concerned none of the commands there enable swipe up/down or transitions from top to bottom or vice versa. You can only change direction from left to right to right to left for pushing and respectively for popping :(

Comment: the "forward" transition animation is a page entry from bottom to top and the "backward" transition animation is top to bottom, by default on `mode="md"` (android) - Check out this [page](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/platform-specific-styles/). In terms of actually setting the navigation active on a swipe, i am not actually sure

Comment: My current workaround has the menu that I want at the bottom on the left. In order to get the transitions animations right I'm using: this.navCtrl.pop({animate: true, direction: 'forward'}); and respectively this.navCtrl.push(LeftPage, {}, {animate: true, direction: 'back'});
But these animate the transitions as swiping the pages in from left to right and out from right to left. So "forward" and "backward". But maybe I'm using mode="md" wrong. Could you please give an example where you would implement mode="md"?

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/config/Config/ `pageTransition: `

Comment: Yeah, more or less :)
I don't know how to explain it. If you ever saw the app snapchat, I'd say just like the memories menu there, which comes up if you swipe from bottom to top :)

Comment: I havnt seen that ...something like this https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-create-a-sliding-drawer-component-for-ionic-2/?

Comment: That is a awesome work around! Thank you for your help :) Not perfect, but it will do the Job for now :)